# Make Modal Update

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

So, I am new to Programming.
i'am trying to make a modal update in laravel,but i don't know how to catch the data on my edit form, i'am trying to search the internet for so long to find a solution. so I hope you all can give me some solution to make update modal.

this my view

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('container')
    <div class="profil-kolom" >
      @foreach ($users as $user) 
        <div class="profil-img">
            @if ($user->profile)
                <img class="img-profilee" width="140px" src="{{ asset('storage/' . $user->profile) }}">
            @else
                <img class="img-profilee" type="file" width="140px" src="/img/default.png">
            @endif
            <div class="fileupload btn">
                <span data-feather="camera" class="camera-profile"></span>
                <span class="btn-text edit-profil">Update Photo</span>
                <a class="dropdown-item upload" href=" " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#Modaledit"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="profil-nama">
            <p>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</p>
        </div>
    
    </div>

     <!-- Modal -->
    
   <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="Modaledit" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-assign">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Upload Photo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form action="{{  route('updateprofile', $user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('put')
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="upload-photo"> 
                    <div class="card card-photo">
                        <img src="/img/default.png" class="card-img-top img-preview img-fluid" alt="...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-photo">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-bar-up ikon-upload" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 10a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V3.707l2.146 2.147a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-3 3a.5.5 0 1 0 .708.708L7.5 3.707V9.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5zm-7 2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                          </svg>
                        <span class="btn-text upload-photo1">Upload Photo</span>
                        <input class="file-photo" type="file" id="profile" name="profile" onchange="previewImage()">
                    </div>
                      
                    <div class="card update-profile">
                        <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                            <div class="form-group input-name">
                                <label>Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}" @error('name') is-invalid @enderror>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('name')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror    
                   
                        <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                            <div class="form-group input-tgl">
                                <label>Tanggal Lahir:</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal_lahir" id="tanggal_lahir" value="{{ auth()->user()->tanggal_lahir }}" @error('tanggal_lahir') is-invalid @enderror>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @error('tanggal_lahir')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror  

                        <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                            <div class="form-group input-tempat-lhr">
                                <label>Tempat Lahir:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tempat_lahir" id="tempat_lahir" value="{{ old('tempat_lahir', $user->tempat_lahir) }}" @error('tempat_lahir') is-invalid @enderror>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @error('tempat_lahir')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                            <div class="form-check form-group input-jk">
                                <label>Jenis Kelamin:</label><br>
                                <div class="form-check" @error('jenis-kelamin') is-invalid @enderror>
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="jenis_kelamin" id="jenis_kelamin" value="pria">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                      Pria
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="jenis_kelamin" id="jenis_kelamin" value="wanita" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                      Wanita
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @error('jenis_kelamin')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                            <div class="form-group input-agama">
                                <label>Agama:</label>
                                <select name="agama" id="agama" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" @error('agama') is-invalid @enderror required>
                                    <option value="" hidden="">Pilih Agama</option>
                                    <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
                                    <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                                    <option value="Budha">Budha</option>
                                    <option value="Kristen">Kristen</option>
                                    <option value="Khatolik">Khatolik</option>
                                    <option value="Konghucu">Khonghucu</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @error('agama')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 @endforeach
  <script>
    function previewImage() {
        const profile = document.querySelector('#profile');
        const imgPreview = document.querySelector('.img-preview');

        imgPreview.style.display = 'block';


        const oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(profile.files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
            imgPreview.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        }
    }
</script>
```

this my route.

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ClassesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuestionsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MemberController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TimeController;
use App\Models\Kelas;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Dashboard;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', ['title' => 'Login']);
});

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);

Route::get('/setup-password/{token}', [PasswordController::class, 'edit'])->name('setup-password-get');
Route::post('/setup-password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])->name('setup-password');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'ceklevel:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/groups/members/{kelas:slug}/addmember', [EmailController::class, 'show']);
    // Route::get('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/groups/quiz/question', [QuestionsController::class, 'create']);
    Route::get('/email', [EmailController::class, 'kirim']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'ceklevel:admin,user']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', function () {
        return view(('home.index'), ['title' => 'home']);
    });
    Route::get('edit', 'ProfileControler@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::get('/classes', [ClassesController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/classes/index/checkSlug', [ClassesController::class, 'checkSlug']);
    Route::get('/groups/{kelas:slug}/posts', [PostsController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('/groups/members/{kelas:slug}/member', [MemberController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/groups/{kelas:slug}/join', [PostController::class, 'join']);
});

Route::post('updateprofile', 'ProfileController@updateprofile')->name('updateprofile');
Route::post('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'upload']);
Route::post('/groups/quiz/question', [QuestionsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/groups/quiz/index', [TimeController::class, 'store']);
Route::resource('/profile', ProfileController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/classes/index', ClassesController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/groups/members/addmember', EmailController::class)->middleware('auth');

// Route::post('kirim', [EmailController::class, 'kirim']);
```

And i build controller like this

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kelas;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('profile.index', [
            'title' => 'Profile',
            'users' => User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {

        return view('profile.index', [
            'title' => 'profile',
            'user' => $user
        ]);

        // $user = User::all();
        // return view('profile.index', compact('user'));

        // return view('profile.index', [
        //     'title' => 'profile',
        //     'user' => $user
        // ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        // return view('profile.index', [
        //     'user' => $user
        // ]);

        $profile = Kelas::findOrfail($request->get('id'));
        echo json_encode($profile);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateprofile(Request $request, User $user)
    {

        $profile = array('kelas' => $request->post('kelas'));
        $save = DB::table('Users')->where('id', '=', $request->post('id'))->update($profile);

        // return $request->file('profile')->store('profile');
        // $path = Storage::putFile('profile', $request->file('profile'));
        // $path = $request->file('profile')->storeAs('profile', 'gambar');
        // $file = $request->file('profile');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kelas;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('profile.index', [
            'title' => 'Profile',
            'users' => User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {

        return view('profile.index', [
            'title' => 'profile',
            'user' => $user
        ]);

        // $user = User::all();
        // return view('profile.index', compact('user'));

        // return view('profile.index', [
        //     'title' => 'profile',
        //     'user' => $user
        // ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        // return view('profile.index', [
        //     'user' => $user
        // ]);

        $profile = Kelas::findOrfail($request->get('id'));
        echo json_encode($profile);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateprofile(Request $request, User $user)
    {

        $profile = array('kelas' => $request->post('kelas'));
        $save = DB::table('Users')->where('id', '=', $request->post('id'))->update($profile);

        // return $request->file('profile')->store('profile');
        // $path = Storage::putFile('profile', $request->file('profile'));
        // $path = $request->file('profile')->storeAs('profile', 'gambar');
        // $file = $request->file('profile');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I didn't know well about javascripts.
i dont't know how to next step, so i hope you all ca help me.
Thanks Before

Comment: A modal is just another form. You put it inside your form tag and get the data same as you would get in your other forms

Answer (score 0):

your button `Update` have attribute `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` , this is for hide the modal remove that attribute. And when you have form at modal you cant only use `<button type="submit>` to post your form you can add action onclick to the button for submit the form like this

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="document.getElementById('form-submit').submit();">Update</button>`

and add attribute id to html `<form>` tag like this

`<form id="form-submit" action="{{  route('updateprofile', $user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`